# .htaccess file not working on windows server for my website, Unable to convert htaccess code to web.config

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web-config, windows-server, web.config-transform

I have windows server for my website, the .htaccess file not working on my server so need to convert my .htaccess file to web.config file.
Unable to convert .htaccess code to web.config... please help in convert the below .htaccess code to web.config code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

by using the link: cbsa.com.br/tools/online-convert-htaccess-to-web-config.aspx

I have try to convert my .htaccess file and it given below code:

```
<rule name="rule 1U" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php/{R:0}"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 2U" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*?)index\.php/*(.*)"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="//{R:1}{R:2}"  />
</rule>
```

When I put this above code in my web.cofig file, my website showing below error...

> Server Error 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the
>   resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

please suggest how to resolve this error...

Comment: http://cbsa.com.br/tools/online-convert-htaccess-to-web-config.aspx

Comment: Dear Mike,
Thanks for your support but I have already used the link to convert my .htaccess file to web.config file... which shows above result.. but by using the above code in web.config file my website show "500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed." please suggest full formatted web.config file and try to resolve my issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all my research and develpoment, I have used below code for web.config for my website at home directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="MyRule"> 
                    <match url="^(.*)$" /> 
                    <conditions> 
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" /> 
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" /> 
                    </conditions> 
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" /> 
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and in CI config/config.php
change

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; ==> $config['index_page'] = '';
```

And its working fine.. url working like www.example.com/home without index.php

Comment: tnx, you saved my day !

Comment: its is great to know :) can you upvote the question if you like?

Comment: wow, thats a great solution by using web.config on windows server